# PHP attributes from simplexml_load)file error Node no longer exists

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

I have been trying to solve this problem now for about 4 hours and will admit that i am novice at php.

The code below is the last I tried.  I have also tried using xpath with no luck.
What am I doing wrong someone please tell me.

```
$url  = "http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/collection?username=wizball&own=1";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$i = 0; 
    foreach($xml->item as $item)
    {
             echo '<div>' . $item->name . '</div>';
             $id=$xml->item[$i]->objectid->attributes();
            $i++

$insert_bgg = sprintf("INSERT INTO trans (objectid, name, yearpublished, image, privatecomment) VALUES ('".$id."','".$item->name."','".$item->yearpublished."','".$item->image."','".$item->privateinfo->privatecomment."')");

echo $insert_bgg;
```

Many thanks in-advance
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I guess your trying to get the data from the page and split it up?

Firstly linking the url does not get the data, take a look at: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/php-get-the-contents-of-a-web-page-rss-feed-or-xml-file-into-a-string-variable/

Then you can pass it into your array using simple xml.

If you need more help let me know.

Comment: many thanks I managed to solve it when I woke up the following morning I endued up using $item['objectid'] and that worked :)